# paypal merchant tech support for direct credit cards eligibility/live credentials

Tags: paypal-rest-sdk, paypal

this is for app in USA. we have integrated our app with iOS SDK and done with sandbox testing and testing with real paypal account. now we'd like to test our app with real credit cards. we got our paypal business account verified by confirming a bank account. our direct credit cards eligibility for live credentials is still pending. there is no phone support for PayPal MTS. how do you resolve such issue? i emailed from both my developer paypal account and merchant account. called paypal support on phone but they asked me to email. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can submit the request to the technical support at the below link :

https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask

Provide your live account information while submitting the request .

Comment: Tried contacting PayPal MTS from both my account (developer) and merchant account. No reply or phone call from PayPal MTS. The status says: 

Note: Live credentials are disabled for direct credit card processing in your app. We are processing your information and will email you when live API credentials are enabled.

Normally how long would this take? a week or a month or few months?

Comment: Yes , it takes usually takes upto three business days.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the APPID takes between 2-3 business days. Sometimes sooner. You can contact PayPal customer service and ask them to check the underwriting timeFrame on your appID. I remember I had to call in on mine and they checked into it for me and I got an approval the next day. Hope this helps. 888.221.1161 for customer service.

Comment: Thank you. It took quite a few hops before we talked to right folks and got this solved. It was enabled on same day.